# Unable to install Math::Pari module

Tags: perl, perl-module, pari

I am trying to install [Crypt::Random](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::Random#HARDWARE-RNG) module, a cryptographically secure random number generator, and says it requires Math::Pari 2.001802, which is not availible from cpan.org, but says it is available from this other URL, which does not work. I tried to install them both anyway and encountered this problem:

```
C:\Users\Jlinne\Documents>                    cpanm Crypt::Random
    --> Working on Crypt::Random
    Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/V/VI/VIPUL/Crypt-Random-1.25.tar.gz ... OK
    Configuring Crypt-Random-1.25 ... OK
    ==> Found dependencies: Math::Pari
    --> Working on Math::Pari
    Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/I/IL/ILYAZ/modules/Math-Pari-2.01080900.zip ... OK
    Configuring Math-Pari-2.01080900 ... N/A
    ! Configure failed for Math-Pari-2.01080900. See C:\Users\Jlinne\.cpanm\work\1476250290.12460\build.log for details.
    ! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Math::Pari' is not installed
    ! Bailing out the installation for Crypt-Random-1.25.

C:\Users\Jlinne\Documents>                    cpanm Math::Pari
    --> Working on Math::Pari
    Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/I/IL/ILYAZ/modules/Math-Pari-2.01080900.zip ... OK
    Configuring Math-Pari-2.01080900 ... N/A
    ! Configure failed for Math-Pari-2.01080900. See C:\Users\Jlinne\.cpanm\work\1476250325.1340\build.log for details.
```

The build.log does not help me either, any other possible ways to install this module successfully? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to share the `build.log` file. Without that we cannot check what caused the failure.

BTW for [Math::Pari](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Pari) you need PARI library. **Starting from version 2.0, this module comes without a PARI library included**.

Since you are trying to install Math-Pari-2.01080900, therefore you will first have to install PARI library.

Get it from http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html

Comment: I can attach the .log file although it will be long, also which Math Pari(s) should I install from http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html for Windows 10 in order to get Math::Pari from cpan? Thanks for helping me out?

Comment: Please let me know if you want me to attach both .log files

Comment: @J.Linne: Pick the stable one from `Self-installing distributions for Windows` section.

Comment: How does cpan's library recognize that I installed Pari 2-7-6. They are in two different locations? When I tried to install Math::Pari from cpan still gives me the same output after I installed Pari 2-7-6. The directories for them I have posted in the question.

Comment: Thanks once again if you could help me fix this issue now that I have Pari 2-7-6.

Comment: Please post the build.log file.

Comment: Chankey can u please comment on @J.Linne comment that what to do after we have Pari installed. How to build Math::Pari using this installed pari.exe

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with using 32 bit Perl, you could use 32 bit [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/), which already has both Math::Pari and Crypt::Random modules installed.

Unfortunately the 64 bit versions of Strawberry Perl do not include either of these modules.  In that case, you'll have to follow the suggestion from Chankey Pathak about installing the PARI library in order to install the Math::Pari module.