# Installing Net::SFTP and Net::SSH2 without CPAN

Tags: perl, sftp, perl-module

I am making a Perl script to fetch files from a Unix Server using SFTP. I want to search the file using Regex and then download it to my system folder. I am using ActivePerl and Windows 64 bit environment. I looked on various posts which suggested the best way is using [Net::SFTP::Foreign::Backend::Net_SSH2](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SFTP-Foreign-Backend-Net_SSH2-0.09/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign/Backend/Net_SSH2.pm) but I am facing lots of errors while installing Net::SFTP and Net::SSH2.I cannot CPAN from my system and tried with GCC and dmake. Net::SFTP is halting at Math::Pari and Net::SSH2 is asking for libraries libssh2. I downloaded libssh2 from [here](https://www.libssh2.org/download/) but not able to install it.

Also can I use any 3-d part OS tools like psftp through Perl to server my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Net::SSH2 is not in offical PPM repositories. Install it using below:

```
ppm install http://www.sisyphusion.tk/ppm/Net-SSH2.ppd
```

Tested on Windows 7 and Perl 5.18.4

[image]

**2.** For Math::Pari check this answer [Unable to install Math::Pari module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991235/unable-to-install-mathpari-module)

Comment: Chankey any 3-d party tool u can suggest which can perform these SFTP Task and can be integrated with Perl. Any Open Source and command line one.

Comment: And can we install Net::SSH2 using CPAN, it is also giving error for missing libraries.